# Can i schedule post using Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, tkinter, facebook-graph-api

I created a small project where you can insert title and image and post it to Facebook, and now I want to add post scheduler. is that possible using the Facebook Graph API(after i select time and date i want it to be scheduled in Facebook, just like [image: this]). or do i have to use my local machine time and date counter so when it reaches the specified time it gets posted.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/common-scenarios#scheduledposts

Answer (score -1):

you can use Crontab in  local machine time
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron